# UISearchController Filter Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

I have a `UITableViewCell` with 3 subviews that I would like to filter when I search, as seen here:

[image: TableViewCell Example]

1.The image view
2.The name label (black text)
3.The street name label (blue text)

This is what I've done so far, I've only managed to understand how to filter 1 array which is the name:

## **MainTableView.swift**

```
var FilteredNames = [String]

     func  updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:UISearchController) {

            // Filter Names
            self.filteredNames = self.names.filter { (name:String) -> Bool in
              if name.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString){
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100.5
        }
    
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            // Search
            if tableView == self.tableView {
                self.streets.count
               return self.names.count
            } else {
              self.filteredStreets.count
            return self.filteredNames.count
            }               
            // return names.count
            }
        
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
           
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
      
            if tableView == self.tableView {
                cell.photo.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
                cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
                cell.streetName.text = streets[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                cell.photo.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
                cell.name.text = self.filteredNames[indexPath.row]
                cell.streetName.text = self.streets[indexPath.row]
            }
            return cell
        }
```

As of right now, when I search, the image view & the street label are not synchronized with the name. I want to filter all 3 subviews to synchronize correctly. How can I achieve this?

I understand i need to use a struct and filter all 3 with one object but i'v encountered some difficulties managing to do that any help will be appreciated thank you !

## **Edit:here is my code right now:**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

  var searchController : UISearchController!
    
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()
    
   // //
        definesPresentationContext = true
        self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        

    
        allUsers = createUsers(names: names, streets: streets, images: images)
            
            filteredUsers = allUsers
            
            }
        
        var allUsers: [User]!
        var filteredUsers: [User]!
        
        func createUsers(names names: [String], streets: [String], images: [UIImage?]) -> [User] {
            var users = [User]()
            guard names.count == streets.count && names.count == images.count else { return users }
            for (index, name) in names.enumerate() {
                let user = User(name: name, streetName: streets[index], image: images[index])
                users.append(user)
            }
            return users
        }
    
    
    
    
        //MARK : Search !
        func  updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:UISearchController) {
            if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercaseString {
                if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
                    filteredUsers = allUsers
                }
                else {
                    filteredUsers = allUsers.filter {
                        return $0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText) ||
                            $0.streetName.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
        {
            return 100.5;
        }
    
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            ////////
            
                   ////////
        }
    
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
            cell.photo.image = user.image
            cell.name.text = user.name
            cell.streetName.text = user.streetName
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Starting from [this moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgEO7nni5CQ&feature=youtu.be&t=2318) see a few minutes of the Stanford course. **H**e is using `didSet` + `reloadData`. I think it's helpful for solving your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to have only one `dataSource` instead of separate arrays for names, street names and images. In the following code `filteredUsers` is always used as dataSource and `allUsers` is just a stored full array, which is used for updating `filteredUsers` every time a new text is entered in search bar.

**Create a model:**

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var streetName: String
    var image: UIImage?
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
var allUsers: [User]!
var filteredUsers: [User]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //assuming you already have three arrays with the same amount of elements in each:
    allUsers = createUsers(names: names, streets: streets, images: images)

    filteredUsers = allUsers
}

func createUsers(names names: [String], streets: [String], images: [UIImage?]) -> [User] {
    var users = [User]()
    guard names.count == streets.count && names.count == images.count else { return users }
    for (index, name) in names.enumerate() {
        let user = User(name: name, streetName: streets[index], image: images[index])
        users.append(user)
    }
    return users
}

func  updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercaseString {
        if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
            filteredUsers = allUsers
        }
        else {
            filteredUsers = allUsers.filter {
                return $0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText) || 
                       $0.streetName.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText)
            } ?? []
        }            
    }
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return filteredUsers ? filteredUsers.count : 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell 
    let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    cell.photo.image = user.image
    cell.name.text = user.name
    cell.streetName.text = user.streetName
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is this an example of your code or its a solution for my situation?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it's solution for your situation. Element is filtered if `streetName` or `name` contains entered search string. By using a single model you will eleminate desyncronized labels, which you are having now.

Comment: `Value of type 'BarsViewController.User' has no member 'image'`                      i get this error

Comment: Oops, there should be `image` instead of `photo` in the struct declaration. Also don't forget to fill `allUsers` array using your data

Comment: whats the template to putting the data please?

Comment: Error #1:`Extraneous argument label 'names:' in call`  Error #2: `Value of type '[String]' has no member 'enumerated'`

Comment: yea Swift 2.3 Sorry should have mentioned it ;)

Comment: Updated again. Add another `names` in function signature and use `enumerate()` instead.

Comment: Still getting an Error Here: `allUsers = createUsers(names: names, streets: streets, images: images)` - `Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage?]' to expected argument type '[UIImage]'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127844/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-newbie-questions).

Comment: return filteredUsers.count is the trouble maker here breakpoints tell